# Ember Image Link-to render

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

i'm having a problem while using images on an ember app, the images just don't render when I change the page through a link-to some route.

The link to is this:

`{{#link-to "login" class="blue-text"}}Login{{/link-to}}`

And the img is here:

`<img src="assets/images/cityLights.jpg" alt="image"/>`

Comment: Here are not enough information to help you. Can you show more code, explain your problem more in detail and at best provide a not working example as an [ember-twiddle](http://ember-twiddle.com/) or an git repo?

Comment: https://github.com/gabrielcarneiro97/PraticoDAW-CLI here is the repo in github, just start the ember serve and try click in some link, you will see that the images won't appear, but if you refresh the page, they will

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not ember related. Remove the surrounding `<div class="parallax">` and it will work.

Probably your UI framework materialize does something with that image at boot time, but your ember `{{link-to}}` does not reinitialize the page but just replace the content.

Comment: You're a genius, you've saved me, ty